# Discrepancy between OpenCV Python and C++ implementations of `imreconstruct`

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm implementing MATLAB's `imreconstruct` in both Python and C++. However, for my test case, the Python implementation matches the MATLAB's output, the C++ one doesn't.

This is the Python implementation:

```py
def imReconstruct(marker: np.array, mask: np.array) -> np.array:
    """
    Naive implementation of MatLAB's imReconstruct function
    works when `mask` consists of mostly background (global minumum)
    will be slow otherwise
    """
    kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

    # calculate the extreme values of the mask image
    min_val, max_val, _, _ = cv.minMaxLoc(mask)

    # clip the marker by global extrema of mask
    _, marker = cv.threshold(marker, min_val, max_val, cv.THRESH_TRUNC | cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    while True:
        expanded = cv.dilate(marker, kernel)
        expanded = np.minimum(expanded, mask)

        # return `expanded` when the difference is small
        if np.max(np.abs(expanded - marker)) < 1e-5:
            return expanded

        # set expanded to marker and repeat
        marker = expanded


D = np.array(
      [[4.2426405, 3.6055512, 3.1622777, 3.       , 3.       ],
       [3.6055512, 2.828427 , 2.236068 , 2.       , 2.       ],
       [3.1622777, 2.236068 , 1.4142135, 1.       , 1.       ],
       [3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       ],
       [3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       ]], dtype=float32)

imReconstruct(D-.85,D)

# output
# array([[3.3926406, 3.3926406, 3.1622777, 3.       , 3.       ],
#        [3.3926406, 2.828427 , 2.236068 , 2.       , 2.       ],
#        [3.1622777, 2.236068 , 1.4142135, 1.       , 1.       ],
#        [3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       ],
#        [3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       ]], dtype=float32)
```

And C++:

```cpp
Mat imReconstruct(Mat marker, Mat mask){
    /**************
     * naive implementation of MatLAB's imReconstruct
     * works when `mask` consist of mostly background (global minimum)
     * will be slow otherwise
     *************/
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3));

    // calculate the min and max values from mask
    double minMask, maxMask;
    minMaxLoc(mask, &minMask, &maxMask);

    // clip the marker by global extrema of mask
    threshold(marker, marker, minMask, maxMask, THRESH_TRUNC|THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Mat expanded;

    // keep filling the holes with `dilate`
    // until there are no more changes
    while (1){
        dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);
        expanded = min(expanded, mask);

        // compute the max difference
        minMaxLoc(expanded-marker, &minMask, &maxMask);

        // return image when changes are small
        if (maxMask<1e-5) return expanded;

        // set expanded as marker and continue looping
        marker = expanded;
    }
}

// test case
cv::Mat D = (cv::Mat_<float> (5,5) <<
       4.2426405, 3.6055512, 3.1622777, 3.       , 3.       ,
       3.6055512, 2.828427 , 2.236068 , 2.       , 2.       ,
       3.1622777, 2.236068 , 1.4142135, 1.       , 1.       ,
       3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
       3.       , 2.       , 1.       , 0.       , 0.       
);

std::cout << imReconstruct(D - .85, D) << std::endl;

// output
// [3.3926406, 3.3926406, 3.1622777, 2.7555513, 2.3122778;
//  3.3926406, 2.8284271, 2.236068, 2, 2;
//  3.1622777, 2.236068, 1.4142135, 1, 1;
//  2.7555513, 2, 1, 0, 0;
//  2.3122778, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

What is the cause of this discrepancy? I may have overlooked something simple, but I already spent few hours in vain without any positive results.

Comment: The only difference I can see is: Python version uses `np.abs(expanded - marker)` in the decision whether to return. In C++ it's only `expanded-marker`.

Comment: No, that's not it. Move `Mat expanded;` to the `while` loop body. The `marker = expanded;` makes them both point to the same buffer. This causes the subsequent `dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);` to modify both (destination already has correct data type and size).

Comment: Really, what bit you was the minor inconsistencies between the two code versions, which could have been avoided. Python `expanded = cv.dilate(marker, kernel)` and C++ `dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);` have slightly different meaning. The first one always allocates a new array for the result. The second only when the destination doesn't match what it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are minor, but significant differences between the Python and C++ implementation of the `while` loop body you presented. Those, coupled with some nuances of how `cv::Mat` and many OpenCV functions work came together to bite you.

The variant of Python code that accurately matches the C++ implementation would look something like the following:

```python
expanded = None
while True:
    expanded = cv.dilate(marker, kernel, expanded)
    expanded = cv.min(expanded, mask, expanded)

    _, max_val, _, _ = cv.minMaxLoc(expanded - marker)

    if max_val < 1e-5:
        return expanded

    marker = expanded
```

This implementation would then suffer from the same issue as the C++ variant, producing the same (incorrect result). But why?

Let's step through the relevant part of C++ code (the `while` loop) and discuss what happens.

### Analysis

We begin with `cv::Mat marker` containing a 5x5 float array, and `cv::Mat expanded` empty.

#### First iteration

We call `cv::dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);`. Internally, [`cv::Mat::create`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a55ced2c8d844d683ea9a725c60037ad0) is called on the destination `expanded`. Since it's empty, a new 5x5 float array is allocated. Dilation is performed and result written to `expanded`'s buffer.

Next step is `expanded = cv::min(expanded, mask);`.

This invokes an overload of [`cv::Mat::operator=`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2a0798475170fb3a23b5bc63686de334) which *"can reuse already allocated matrix if it has the right size and type to fit the matrix expression result"*. Hence, this is equivalent to call to [`cv::min`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga9af368f182ee76d0463d0d8d5330b764), specifically `cv::min(expanded, mask, expanded);`.
Like before, `cv::Mat::create` is called on the destination `expanded`. This time it already contains a 5x5 float array, so no allocation happens, and the buffer is reused. The calculation is done in-place, and after the call, `expanded` still refers to the same chunk of memory.

Next the `cv::minMaxLoc` runs on result of `expanded - marker`. Nothing surprising here, the two are different arrays. The `maxMask` is not less than `1e-5`, so we continue.

#### Problem Starts

Trouble begins with the final statement in the loop body, `marker = expanded;` — a **shallow copy**. This invokes a different overload of [`cv::Mat::operator=`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302).

*"Matrix assignment is an O(1) operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared and the reference counter, if any, is incremented."*

That means that after this point, both `marker` and `expanded` refer the the same 5x5 float array, with reference count of 2. With this in mind, we proceed to second iteration.

#### Second Iteration

We call `cv::dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);`. Destination is already 5x5 float array, no allocation happens, and result is written to `expanded`'s buffer (which is still shared with `marker`).

Next, `expanded = cv::min(expanded, mask);`. Destination is already 5x5 float array, no allocation happens, and result is written to `expanded`'s buffer (which is still shared with `marker`).

#### Failure

Finally, the `cv::minMaxLoc` runs on result of `expanded - marker`... but both of those really refer to the same data, so it's rather `expanded - expanded`, and that's just all zeros. Therefore, the test `(maxMask < 1e-5)` succeeds and the loop terminates prematurely.

---

### Solution 1

Ensure that new `expanded` is allocated on each iteration, as happens in the Python version of the code. Do this by simply moving declaration of `expanded` into the loop body.

**Code:**

```cpp
// ...
while (true) {
    cv::Mat expanded;
    cv::dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);
    expanded = cv::min(expanded, mask);

    cv::minMaxLoc(expanded - marker, nullptr, &maxMask);
    if (maxMask < 1e-5) { return expanded; }

    marker = expanded;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3.3926406, 3.3926406, 3.1622777, 3, 3;
 3.3926406, 2.8284271, 2.236068, 2, 2;
 3.1622777, 2.236068, 1.4142135, 1, 1;
 3, 2, 1, 0, 0;
 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

### Solution 2

Instead of shallow copy, perform a deep copy. This is done by calling [`cv::Mat::copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77).

**Code:**

```cpp
Mat expanded;
while (true) {
    cv::dilate(marker, expanded, kernel);
    expanded = cv::min(expanded, mask);

    cv::minMaxLoc(expanded - marker, nullptr, &maxMask);
    if (maxMask < 1e-5) { return expanded; }

    expanded.copyTo(marker);
}
```

Output is identical to that of solution 1.

NB: The Python equivalent of this would be `np.copyto(expanded, marker)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. In a way, it's a simple thing once you pointed it out. But I believe I wouldn't been able to find it on my own ever.